# How to get all network printers in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

Please any one help me  to get all network printers.
I get all printers installed in the local machine using "System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters".

But I can't get the printers which are in the Network.
I try with "ManagementObjectSearcher" but I can't access this class.
I think it does not support in framework 4.0.

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0, C#. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Singaravelu.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you cannot find/reference the [ManagementObjectSearcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) probably is because you did not add the proper reference to: [System.Management.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) to your C# project. Surely it is supported also by .NET 4.

as you can see in this question: [ManagementObjectSearcher select network printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264888/managementobjectsearcher-select-network-printers) you can find all network printers in this way:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
var results = searcher.Get();

IList<ManagementBaseObject> printers = new List<ManagementBaseObject>();

foreach (var printer in results) {
    if ((bool)printer["Network"]) {
        printers.Add(printer);
    }
}
```