# How to list all the printer connected on the network using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to list all the active printer's name connected in the network in the drop down box by using c# language. is it possible to do that in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all connected printers using the GetPrintQueue function in the PrintServer class in the System.Printing namespace.  [Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/927/wpf-print-queues-and-capabilities) is the good sample for this.

Then add them to your list for the drop down.

Also, either do a better search here on stackoverflow (you might find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer-c-sharp-winform?rq=1) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581044/how-to-get-all-network-printers-in-asp-net-4-0?rq=1)), or at least mention what you've got so far and what research you've done.

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(printer);
    }
```